# Invalid JSon error for JQuery.parseJSON

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to parse the following string to JSON object.It is giving me error. I could not find out why.

```
var json1 = "{'firstName': 'John','lastName': 'Smith', 'age': 25, 'address': {'streetAddress': '21 2nd Street','city': 'New York','state': 'NY', 'postalCode': '10021'}, 'phoneNumber':   [ {'type': 'home','number': '212 555-1234'},  {'type': 'fax', 'number': '646 555-4567' }]}";
$.parseJSON(json1);
```

Comment: here is the valid json https://gist.github.com/2708753

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use double quotes `"` both for keys and string values: see [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)

If you change all occurrences of single quotes with double quotes your JSON is valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
var json1 = '"result":[{"firstName": "John","lastName": "Smith", "age": 25, "address": [{"streetAddress": "21 2nd Street","city": "New York","state": "NY", "postalCode": 10021}, "phoneNumber":   [ {"type": "home","number": 212 555-1234"},  {"type": "fax", "number": 6465554567 }]]}]";
```